# Adding bootstrap CSS class Attribute to textbox ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

When adding a css class attribute using `new { @class="form-control"}` to a textbox generated using html helpers, the attribute is added as a value while the same approach works fine with the `textarea` control.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New</h2>
<div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Title");
                @Html.TextBox("Title", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Body")
                @Html.TextArea("Body", new{ @class="form-control"} )
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-default" name="edit" value="edit"/>
            <input class="btn btn-default" name="save" value="Save" />
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this overload of `Html.TextBox` for method

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    object value
)
```

and the second parameter sets the value of the input, if model state dictionary does not contain one for the input. So your code will render something like this

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="{ class = form-control }">
```

You should use this overload which takes the value and htmlAttriubutes

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    object value,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

Use it like this

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Interesting thing to note here is, the helper method will look for the value in model state dictionary and view state dictionary as well. So if your action method is setting the `ViewBag.Title` to some value, that value will be used as the value of the input if you pass `null` as the value when calling this method.  The default MVC project template uses `ViewBag.Title` to set the page title. So you probably are going to see that value in the input.

To solve that, you can explicitly pass an empty string instead of `null`

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: This approach worked, the `textbox`  was rendered  correctly, only the `textbox` control has a value of `new`by default

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the answer. Are you setting `ViewBag.Title="New"` in the action method ? You can explicitly pass `string.empty` instead of `null`. See the update in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead  `@Html.TextBox("Title","", new { @class = "form-control" })`

The over load you're currently using is

```
HtmlHelper.TextBox(string name, object value)
```